# `lifetime arguments are not allowed for this type` in trait with generic result type

Tags: rust

```
pub struct Article<'a> {
    pub id: &'a str,
    pub title: &'a str,
    pub content: &'a str,
    pub description: &'a str,
}
```

```
pub struct Diary<'a> {
    pub id: &'a str,
    pub title: &'a str,
    pub content: &'a str,
}
```

Using trait to abstract the method with the type has lifetime but the error is confusing. How can I handle lifetime parameter in generic result type in trait.

```
pub trait Publish<'a, T: 'a> {
    fn publish(self) -> Result<T, Error>;
}

impl<'a> Publish<'a> for Article<'a> {
    fn publish(self) -> Result<Article<'a>, Error> {
        let result = Article {
            id: self.id,
            title: self.title,
            content: self.content,
            description: self.description,
        };

        Ok(result.render())
    }

}

impl<'a> Publish<'a> for Diary<'a> {
  fn publish(self) -> Result<Diary<'a>, Error> {
  // almost samle as below
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Why do you need `T` here? Is this the real code?

Answer (score 2):

The way you'd express this is with a bound on the generic type `T`:

```
pub trait Publish<'a, T: 'a> {
    fn publish(self) -> Result<T, Error>;
}
```

However, this raises the question of *why* you need the lifetime here.  The answer is that you don't, and you can leave that detail up to the trait implementations, so your trait should be:

```
pub trait Publish<T> {
    fn publish(self) -> Result<T, Error>;
}
```

Now you need to fix your implementations.  They shouldn't have a generic parameter `T` in the first place since their types are fully known -- since the return type of the method is `Result<Article<'a>, Error>` for example, we know that the trait's `T` is `Article<'a>`.

This is also the right place to convey the lifetime information, as mentioned above.

So, your implementations would change to:

```
impl<'a> Publish<Article<'a>> for Article<'a> {
```

```
impl<'a> Publish<Diary<'a>> for Diary<'a> {
```